# Mule ESB Database Insert working only after Mule restart

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, mule

I am trying to insert to MySQL using a for-each since my input JSON can have multiple values.

`employee id`, `projectname` and `startdate` are mandatory and only they are inserted to database every time.

Though other fields may come in, they are inserted to database only after Mule is restarted. This code works after restarting Mule (inserting all values) and then suddenly it stops working again (inserting only mandatory values), then working again after restart.

I enabled the logging, and I can see the JSON input is in correct format.

Below is my Mule configuration xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <flow name="addprojectdetailsFlow1" doc:name="addprojectdetailsFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP" path="addProjectDetails"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <!--  logger message="#[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/-->
        <foreach collection="#[payload.newprojects.projects]" doc:name="For Each">
            <db:insert config-ref="testMysqlLocal" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO Project (employee_id, projectname, notes, StartDate, EndDate, ClientRate, EmployeeRate) VALUES (#[payload.employeeid],#[payload.projectname],#[payload.notes],#[payload.StartDate],#[payload.EndDate],#[payload.ClientRate],#[payload.EmployeeRate]);]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
        </foreach>
        <response>
            <http:response-builder doc:name="HTTP Response Builder">
                <http:header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
                <http:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
            </http:response-builder>
        </response>
        <response>
            <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
        </response>
        <response>
            <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="/AnypointStudio/workspace/databasetest/validateaddProjectDetailsResponse.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        </response>
        <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    </flow>
</mule>

Here is my Json sample.

{
    "newprojects": {
        "projects": [
            {
                "employeeid": "2",
                "projectname": "1112",
                "notes": "projectanotes",
                "StartDate": "2015-01-01",
                "EndDate": "2015-01-01",
                "ClientRate": "20",
                "EmployeeRate": "20"
            },
            {
                "employeeid": "2",
                "projectname": "1121",
                "notes": "projectanotes",
                "StartDate": "2015-01-01",
                "EndDate": "2015-01-01",
                "ClientRate": "20",
                "EmployeeRate": "20"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Has anyone out there faced the same issue or see anything amiss here?

Comment: To be honest , I have tested your flow and JSON input with my SQL server and I got data to be inserted successfully and and couldn't able recreate the same issue ..

Comment: Thanks for checking on it. Nothing yet on my side too. I will update if I see this error again.

Comment: I see this issue again. Here is the input request coming in mule but only the projectname, employee_id and StartDate are getting inserted. INFO  
INFO  2015-08-15 15:45:04,643 [[databasetest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.05] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: {newprojects={projects=[{employeeid=2, projectname=1112, notes=projectanotes, StartDate=2015-01-01, EndDate=2015-01-01, ClientRate=20, EmployeeRate=x}, {employeeid=2, projectname=1121, notes=projectanotes, StartDate=2015-01-01, EndDate=2015-01-01, ClientRate=20, EmployeeRate=20}]}}. I know restart will fix the issue.